# Как перенаправить пользователя в личный профиль по id из базы данных?

Tags: php, mysqli

не могу перенаправить пользователя, по идеи он входит в аккаунт, на который уже присвоен id, не понимаю как перенаправить его на страницу профиля где будет id

```
<?php
require "db_connect.php";
session_start();

$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$md5_password = md5($password); //шифрование пароля
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login`='{$login}' AND 
`password`='{$md5_password}'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1) {
$_SESSION['user'] = ['nick' => $login];
header('Location: /');
}else{
   echo("Ошибка: Данный логин или пароль не верный.");
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0):

```
require "db_connect.php";
session_start();

$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login`=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $login);
$stmt->execute();
$user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
if ($user && $user['password'] === $password) {
    $_SESSION['user'] = $usr;
    header("Location: /profile/{$user['id']}");
    exit;
} else {
    echo("Ошибка: Данный логин или пароль не верный.");
}
```

md5 в обязательном порядке заменить на password_hash/password_verify

Comment: Проверять входящие данные желательно, но не обязательно. А вот почитать про SQL инъекции вам просто необходимо